# How does the COMP/EN pin of the MAX1967/MAX1966 work?

Tags: pwm, buck

I know this question may seem simple to more experienced people but I struggle to understand how the COMP/EN pin works on this particular IC.
I want to use it for a buck converter that has external control loops and I would like to bypass the internal error amplifier and feed my control signal directly to the COMP pin. Is that possible? and if so should my control signal (I have voltage references bigger than 0.8V on the external loops) be scaled to 0 - 0.8V externally and then feed to the COMP pin? Or does the IC handle the scale automatically?

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do exactly, but no, you can't drive COMP/EN with a control voltage. It can be grounded to disable the output, otherwise it's an RC compensation network connected to the error amplifier's output. The chip will output whatever voltage it has to to make the voltage to the FB input pin match the internal 0.8V reference.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am a bit confused because I don't know if the negative input of the error comparator can be accessed directly through the COMP/EN pin. And I also don't know if the error amplifier has a negative feedback, because if it does I can probably connect my control voltage on the FB pin. I hope this makes sense, I'm new to this.

Comment: The error amplifier negative input is fixed at 0.8V so while you could feed a control voltage into FB the error amplifier output would just slam high or low depending on whether it is above or below 0.8V, and when it's low it will just turn everything off, same as grounding COMP/EN. You may want to step back and explain the big picture of what you're trying to do and why you need "external control loops" - smarter people than me may then weigh in with suggestions.